# showing that ${kp^2\choose jp^2} \equiv {k\choose j}$ modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Given $1\le k \le p-1$ and $1\le j \le k$, show that
${kp^2\choose jp^2} \equiv {k\choose j}$ modulo $p$ where $p$ is some prime integer. Could I receive some hints? I tried writing the expressions but they don't seem to do much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Consider first the expansion

$$(x+1)^p=\sum_{\ell=0}^p\binom{p}\ell x^\ell\;.$$

- Show that if $1\le\ell\le p-1$, then $\binom{p}\ell$ is divisible by $p$.

This implies that

$$(x+1)^p\equiv 1+x^p\pmod p$$

for integer values of $x$.

- Now use this result to prove (again for integer $x$) that $$(1+x)^{p^2}\equiv 1+x^{p^2}\pmod p\;.$$
- Finally, apply the binomial theorem to $(1+x)^{kp^2}$ and to $\left(1+x^{p^2}\right)^k$ and consider the coefficients of $x^{jp^2}$ in the two expansions.